# Быстро выбрать первый элемент из массива по классу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Хочу применить функцию к первому элементу из масива который достаёт jquery но получаю ошибку:

```
$(...)[0].addClass is not a function
```

Достаю вот так:

```
$('.slider-image')[0].addClass('hide-slider-left');
```

Если вывожу таким способом в консоль элемент то видно что его находит:

```
console.log($('.slider-image')[0]);
```

Comment: используйте .first()

Comment: а если мне нужно будет найти не первый а определенный по числу?

Comment: [0] возвращает не jqyery элемент как можно было бы ожидать, а dom element у которого просто нет таких методов. $($('.slider-image')[0]); или более сложный селектор по типу nth-child

Comment: @Horchynskyi :nth-child(n)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
let item = $('.slider-image')[0];
$(item).addClass("Ваш Класс");
```

Comment: работает. Но можно ли обойти как-то без создания переменной?

Comment: @Horchynskyi легко - `document.querySelector('.slider-image').classList.add("Ваш Класс");`. Выкиньте jquery на помойку, вы еще не раз отхлебнёте из за него подобных проблем

Comment: @Darth  я так понял использование jquery обязательно